# Magento 2.1.7: Unable to process binding "attr: function (){return {id:'billing-address-same-as-shipping-'+ getCode($parent)} }"

Tags: magento2

I get an error on my checkout payment page:

```
knockout.js:3012 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "attr: function (){return {id:'billing-address-same-as-shipping-'+ getCode($parent)} }"
Message: getCode is not defined
    at attr (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:3:158)
    at update (knockout.js:3659)
    at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3004)
    at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
    at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
    at knockout.js:3002
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2854)
    at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2836)
```

Does somebody knows how to get this fixed?